# Footer label going outside the horizontal scroll bar in primeng datatable

Tags: angular, primeng

I used angular PrimeNg DataTable in which I want to show both header and footer label in the table. But the footer not set properly.
Here is my HTML code:

```html
<p-dataTable [value]="cars" scrollable="true" scrollHeight="200px" scrollWidth="600px" [style]="{'margin-top':'30px'}">
        <p-header>Vertical and Horizontal</p-header>
        <p-column field="vin" header="Vin" footer="Vin" [style]="{'width':'250px'}"></p-column>
        <p-column field="year" header="Year" footer="Year" [style]="{'width':'250px'}"></p-column>
        <p-column field="brand" header="Brand" footer="Brand" [style]="{'width':'250px'}"></p-column>
        <p-column field="color" header="Color" footer="Color" [style]="{'width':'250px'}"></p-column>
    </p-dataTable>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

add this style to your component for a work-around

```
>>> .ui-datatable-scrollable-footer {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

caveat: using `>>>` is not a super good idea, see https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep